# Change loaded div from another page with another one on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an index.php page that holds and loads all the content so it wont be neccessary to load to other pages and everything happens dynamically. So lets say i have a div in the index.php:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and i have a full content.php file that holds most of the divs/pages:

```
<div id="cont1">something :
   <div id="innercont1"><a href="#">Dynamic click</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="changeinnercont1">
   <img src="images/pic.jpg" />
</div>
```

so far so good but the jQuery\Ajax script isnt working in index.php where it should manipulate the divs from content.php. This is the script that loads onclick event the divs in #content from index.php and its working perfectly:

```
$("#content").fadeOut("slow",function(){
  $("#content").load("content.php #cont1");
  $("#content").fadeIn();
});
```

But when it loads this content from the content.php and when i click the link text nothing happens because of the another script in index.php that isnt working properly:

```
$(function () {
    $("#innercont1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#innercont1").load("content.php #changeinnercont1");
    });
});
```

I think the browser isnt holding the loaded div from another page but only the #content from its own(index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `("#innercont1").click` event listener is created, there is no element in the DOM with the id innercont1, since that element is dynamically loaded from elsewhere. What you need for this instance is an event listener that will catch any element with that id at any time. You can bind the listener to the body element instead, like so:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#innercont1', function(){
    //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your click event listener is being bound before `#innercont1` exists. What happens if you load and bind the listener all in one block, e.g.

```
$("#content").fadeOut("slow",function(){
  $("#content").load("content.php #cont1");
  $("#innercont1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#innercont1").load("content.php #changeinnercont1");
  });
  $("#content").fadeIn();
});
```